# Are carob beans poisonous?

Tags: carob

I used to pick up carob bean pods off the sidewalk.

My mother told me to drop the carob immediatly, and my mother told me that the carob beans were poisonous.

I looked up the latin name for carob beans.

The latin name is Ceratonia siliqua.

Is Ceratonia siliqua poisonous?

I saw a youtube video saying that dog treats can be made from carob.

Comment: Its possible your mother just didn't want you picking random seedpods off the ground and eating them.

Comment: I sure hope not. I eat them in energy bars. They taste like chocolate.

Comment: @DKNguyen I regularly eat kidney beans in food products. That doesn't mean they aren't poisonous to eat from the pod.

Comment: I find carob chips taste like... chocolate-dipped raisins. Both of which, unlike carob, are poisonous to dogs. Go figure.  Carob is often used in dog treats as a canine-safe chocolate replacement, but it doesn't taste exactly the same.

Comment: @PeteKirkham You can say the same thing about potatoes. But you don't tell a child to immediately drop a potato because it's poisonous.

Comment: @DKNguyen the potatoes which are commonly grown for food are not poisonous, just unpleasant to eat raw, so are safe for children to handle, e.g. making potato prints. Eating a few raw kidney beans will result in vomiting and diarrhoea, so I wouldn't allow a child young enough to be at the putting things in mouth age to handle them.

Answer (score 22):

No, they’re not poisonous. Carob beans are edible and widely eaten, in particular as a disappointing chocolate substitute as well as a thickener (locust bean gum) derived from the seeds. Of course, some carob beans - particularly ones not intended for consumption - may have had pesticides sprayed on them.

Your mother may have been thinking of castor beans, which are quite poisonous.

Comment: Another consideration: often the same everyday name gets used for different plants in different places.  E.g. “chestnut” is used for a lot of different trees and their nuts, including some edible species and some poisonous ones.  So the trees that OP knows as “carob” may not necessarily be the same species *Ceratonia siliqua* that commercial carob beans come from.

Answer (score 6):

No, they are not poisonous.
Allow me to assume that your mother was trying to say that they could be poisonous because they grow near a road and therefore can contain lead and other toxic chemicals that can do long-term damage, but could not explain. Or maybe she really thought they were poisonous.

Comment: It could also be that she said something along the lines of, "You shouldn't eat random things off of plants; they could be poisonous," which a young mind could easily interpret as "Those are poisonous."